# Does masturbating everynight cause problems in the future?

Tags: medical-science, sexuality, healthcare, masturbation

> Did you know that plain and simple, over-masturbation will lead to
>   sexual under performance by way of premature ejaculation, as well as
>   other sexual problems. “Over-production of sex hormones”  Normally,
>   masturbation is a healthy sexual behavior. But like other behaviors,
>   when over practiced it (maximum 2 times a week) can lead to both
>   psychological and physiological imbalances. Frequent masturbation and
>   ejaculation will stimulate the acetylcholine/parasympathetic nervous
>   functions. Excessive masturbation and ejaculation can, and often times
>   will, result in over-production of sex hormones and neurotransmitters
>   such as acetylcholine, dopamine and serotonin. An unnatural abundance
>   of these hormones and neurotransmitters can cause the brain and
>   adrenal glands to perform excessive
>   dopamine-norepinephrine-epinephrine conversion, in turn, making the
>   brain and bodily functions perform at an extreme level. In other
>   words, there is a huge change in body chemistry when one masturbates
>   excessively.[1](http://abchomeopathy.com/forum2.php/48321/)

[Article about risks of masturbating from ABC Homeopathy](http://abchomeopathy.com/forum2.php/48321/)

Is this true?

Comment: Could you please work out the **relevant** claim and leave out irrelevant details, focusing on one point, please? A quoted wall of text won’t elicit many answers, I fear.

Comment: The quote contains elements of scientific observation wrapped up in far too much opinion and conjecture, all presented as if its fact. There is little doubt that our persistent behaviours in any area have long term effects on how our brain deals with our body, but there is no reason to have confidence in this persons competence in this area. The advice is given on a homeopathy and health forum by people identified as "non-medical professionals". 

All that said, it seems likely that there is the potential for frequent masturbation to affect a tendency to premature ejaculation in some people.

Comment: I've been conducting a detailed study on this for over a decade and so far I can report no ill effects what-so-ever. Although admittedly my sample size is only 1.